# Grafana pull two measurements combine multiple fileds in grafana metrics from influxdb

Tags: flux, influxdb, grafana

I want to show virtual machine monitoring data by grafana，so has installed grafana + influxdb by docker images，and import zabbix data into influxdb. i need merge queries for multriple fields from two measurements in grafana table metrics。

how to merge cloumn CPU(%) and business_system to a row in below image?

[grafana question image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GhnM.png)

Can  [flux](https://grafana.com/plugins/grafana-influxdb-flux-datasource) plugin do it? Any ideas are welcome or any other way round to achieve the result.

Comment: Can you share more details and format your question?

Comment: Sorry, My English is poor, and  have updated。

Comment: I believe what you are trying to do IS capable of being done using Flux through influxDB and the Flux plugin available for Grafana.  I am currently doing multiple queries, and series wise math between query results, and graphing those.